# Set column description from PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

PowerBI supports column descriptions (right click on a column and select properties), is there a way to set this column description from PowerQuery. It seems hard to believe this isn't possible, but I can't find it in the documentation for PowerQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this myself for a while. At the time being this does not seem to be possible. There's nothing in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/power-query-m-reference), and not even in the [ideas section](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas) in the forum **or** in the `Preview Features` as of September 2019:

[image]

I know this is not what you were hoping for, and I really do hope someone is able to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Powerbi uses SSAS in the background. The column descriptions are stored in DMVs.`MDSCHEMA_MEASURES`, `TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS` & `TMSCHEMA_MEASURES`

You can set them in SSAS (if your using SSAS tabular as a source for your model) or view the PBI descriptions via DAX studio https://insightsquest.com/2017/12/14/query-power-bi-field-descriptions/  unfortunately I don't believe these can be set in PowerQuery

Answer (score 0):

Found it! When defining a table column's type, instead of simply adding a datatype like `text`, you can specify a datatype with metadata like `(type text meta [MetadataField1 = ...])` and the metadata fields you want to set are "**Documentation.FieldDescription**" and "**Documentation.FieldCaption**".

Once you've set up a table type, you can use it within any function that takes a table type as an argument, such as `#table`, `Value.ReplaceType`, `Table.FromColumns`, etc.

### Example

```ml
let
  TableType = type table [
    ID = (Int64.Type meta [
      Documentation.FieldDescription = "Unique identifier for this record.",
      Documentation.FieldCaption = "Primary Key"
    ]),
    Data = text
  ],
  Table = #table(
    TableType,
    {
      {1, "asdf"},
      {2, "fdsa"}
    }
  ),
  Schema = Table.Schema(Table),
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(
    Schema,
    {"Name", "TypeName", "FieldCaption", "Description"}
  )
in
  #"Removed Other Columns"
```

The above returns a table of:

| Name | TypeName | FieldCaption | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | Int64.Type | Primary Key | Unique identifier for this record. |
| Data | Text.Type | *null* | *null* |